# Can't find/replace correctly

Tags: regex, excel, csv, parsing, vba

I have a CSV file I'm trying to remove the HTML tags from, and all line returns.

Doing a find/replace with `<*>` returns the "There's a problem with this formula" error.

Trying `\<*>` gets the error "We can't find anything to replace."

Trying this VBA does nothing either - it runs successfully, but all the tags are still there:

```
Sub t()
With Range("A1:AE60165")
    .Replace Chr(10), " "
    .Replace Chr(13), " "
    .Replace vbCr, " "
    .Replace vbLf, " "
    .Replace vbCrLf, " "
    .Replace "<*>", ""
End With
End Sub
```

That macro also does *not* remove any line breaks or carriage returns.  Also doing a find/replace with `Char!10)` or `Char(13)` doesn't do anything either.

A final thing I tried is `Worksheetfunction.Clean(Range("A1"))` which also does nothing. **But** if in `A2`, I use `=CLEAN(A1)`, it successfully removes the line breaks.  I can't do that on all cells though as the dataset is quite large.

I can't even remove `@` successfully from all cells. I just ran it, it removed 23 instances, but even the cell I have selected has an `@` but *wasn't* removed.

I suspect it's something with the CSV, as I don't know why it's being so complicated.  It's a lot of data so a function wouldn't likely be the best option.

Is it perhaps some Unicode type issue?

Edit: FWIW, I'm using the `profiles.csv` found [here](https://github.com/rudeboybert/JSE_OkCupid), as I learn Python it's just to play around with.  [Here's a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ydUxXdsw) link to a small amount of that data, but I'm not sure how well it "translates" on that site.

Comment: have you tried searching for it as a regular expression.
<.*>  should get all the html tags in regular expression context

Comment: @GerriePretorius - I'm not very good with regex.  What would I search for? I am just trying to remove all line breaks/carriage returns and any HTML tags, i.e. `<a href ...>`, `<br>`, `</br>`, etc.

Comment: <.*>   this regular expression means the following:
< is start searching for a string starting with < 
. means anything 
* of any lenght
> ending with this
So just makes sure you have the dot inthere as well

Comment: if you install regexcoach you can put some demo text in, and it will highlight the text that matches your regex, so you can then see if it is doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: @GerriePretorius - I tried `<.*>` and still nothing, I get "We couldn't find anything to replace..."

Comment: Can you share a small sample file you are having issue with?

Comment: @sktneer - sure! See my edit.  ...I hope it helps. I'm not used to posting to off-site places for data, so let me know if there's a better option (or if I can somehow paste it here, without making the textbox with my data wildly huge and annoying)

Comment: You can upload the file at Google Drive or DropBox and may share the link.

Comment: Also when I open the profiles.csv, it looks all fine. Where is the issue in that file?

Comment: @sktneer - Really? It doesn't have a bunch of cells like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7xW3.jpg)?

Comment: Oh yes, I see them.

Comment: If I take the example of the cell G3, after running your macro, it does what it is supposed to do. I get all the content in 1 line with no <> tags. Can you tell which specific cell is still having issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157352/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-sktneer).

Comment: If you actually want to see all the G3 content in one line, you will need to turn Wrap Text off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using notepad++ for this, it will be much easier, alternatively you can import the CSV in SQL and do the replace there as well

Comment: Notepad++ also can't find `<*>`...and only found three instances of `\n`.

Comment: Ah! If I turn on the RegEx check, I can remove the `<.*>` successfully. I'll have to see how to remove the new line breaks.

Comment: Thats great! try searching for unicode Alt 0010 and replace by a space to remove the line breaks.
Open the search & replace box and in search string just hold Alt key and type 0010 you wont see any character there in replace by just put a blank space hit the search and replace to remove the line breaks

Comment: ....how do I search for the Unicode Alt 0010? (I've had Notepad++ forever, just never used it so I'm not sure what to do here)

Comment: if this search trick dosent works in notepad++ try using the new file with tags removed in Excel, Excel will find the Alt0010 character

Comment: Turns out, if you read comments, doing the Notepad++ to remove the `<*>` worked, and I just reran my macro and turned off TextWrapping, and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a function call to illustrate the procedure. You should be in the position to make these calls in loop, preferrably in an array loop and to write results back afterwards to improve performance.

**Example call**

```
Sub test_RemoveHTML()
Dim s As String: s = "<b>xxx</b><div />"
MsgBox RemoveHTML(s)
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

```
Function RemoveHTML(s As String) As String
' Purpose: remove HTML tags and comments from string via regular expression
On Error GoTo oops
Dim oRegEx   As Object       ' Late Binding
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With oRegEx
    '.Pattern = "<[^>]+>"      'basic html pattern
    .pattern = "<!*[^<>]*>"    'html tags and comments
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With

RemoveHTML = oRegEx.Replace(s, "")

leaveFunction:
On Error Resume Next
Set oRegEx = Nothing            ' clear memory
Exit Function

oops:
MsgBox "Error No " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, _
       vbExclamation, "RemoveHTML"
Resume leaveFunction
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have a bunch of data (`Range(A1:AE60000)`), so a function may not be the best option.

Comment: Just remaining withing VBA: Why not operating with a `Join` function and doing the regex all in one?